# Grails easygrid plugin filter by toString()

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails easygrid plugin.

```
ownerGrid {
            dataSourceType 'gorm'
            domainClass Owner
            gridImpl 'dataTables'
            fixedColumns true
            columns {
                room
                { label "owner.room.label" 
                    type 'text'
                    value {owner->owner.room.toString()}
                    filterClosure { filter ->
                        room {
                                ilike(...., "%${filter.paramValue}%")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I don't know a lot about how criterias are built in grails, but i would like to compare the toString() value of the room class.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the 'Room' domain object has some sort of name property ( which you would use in the toString method).

Or, if it's more complicated, you probably generate toString from 2 or more columns. In this case you could use: [Gorm derived properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) . Let's call this derived property: 'derivedName'. This is how your grid would look like:

```
    ownerGrid {
        dataSourceType 'gorm'
        domainClass Owner
        gridImpl 'dataTables'
        fixedColumns true
        columns {
            room {
                label "owner.room.label"
                type 'text'
                property owner.room.derivedName
                filterClosure { filter ->
                    room {
                        ilike('derivedName', "%${filter.paramValue}%")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i want. if I want the derivedName to be Hotel.name + RoomType.name, is it possible, or i can only get the id from SQL ?

Comment: I guess it depends. Is RoomType an enum? How do you store it in the db?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way... unless you save the output of `toString()` method in extra property of your `Owner` DC so you can fire a query against it. 
Although it's a bad idea in many aspects